# How to compress files include subfolder based on a file modification date

Tags: debian, terminal, zip

I like to make a script file to backup a upload folder (that have big size), problem is script will backup every midnight so it's quite big zip file.

**1st March**

```
Upload
├── sub01/
│   ├── file-01.jpg (1 mar)
│   ├── file-02.jpg (1 mar)
│   ├── file-03.jpg (1 mar)
│   └── file-04.jpg (1 mar)
├── sub02/
│   ├── file-05.jpg (1 mar)
│   └── file-06.jpg (1 mar)
```

I was wonder how we can make a zip for each day for backup example
At the day one (example 1st March) will be a big zip file then next day will zip only
create/modify only in 2nd March and keep backup everyday.

**2nd March**

```
Upload
    ├── sub01/
    │   ├── file-01.jpg (1 mar)
    │   ├── file-02.jpg (1 mar)
    │   ├── file-03.jpg (2 mar)
    │   └── file-04.jpg (1 mar)
    ├── sub02/
    │   ├── file-05.jpg (1 mar)
    │   └── file-06.jpg (1 mar)
    └── sub03/
        ├── file-07.jpg (2 mar)
        ├── file-08.jpg (2 mar)
        ├── file-09.jpg (2 mar)
        └── file-01.jpg (2 mar)
```

The `02032022.zip` will contain file

```
Upload
    ├── sub01/
    │   └── file-03.jpg (2 mar)
    └── sub03/
        ├── file-07.jpg (2 mar)
        ├── file-08.jpg (2 mar)
        ├── file-09.jpg (2 mar)
        └── file-01.jpg (2 mar)
```

how can we make a script file for cron to zip it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU find/awk and bsdtar (in `libarchive-tools` package in newer versions of Debian)

```
LC_ALL=C find . -iname '*.jpg' -type f -printf '%p\0%TF\0' |
  gawk -v RS='\0' -v  ORS='\0' '
    {
      getline date
      print | "bsdtar --format zip --null -T - -cf "date".zip"
    }'
```

Would create some `YYYY-MM-DD.zip`¹ files containing the `jpg` files last modified on the corresponding date.

Note that it will likely  run many of those `bsdtar` commands in parallel. If you have files last modified on many different days, it could overwhelm your system.

To only create a zip file for files last modified the previous day (local time), you'd do:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -iname '*.jpg' -daystart -mtime 1 -print0 |
  bsdtar --format zip --null -T - -cf "$(date -d yesterday +%F).zip"
```

---

<sup>That's a much better format than your `DDMMYYYY.zip` as it's unambiguous and means the file names sort the same lexically and chronologically, but if you insist in using that, you can replace `%TF` with `%Td%Tm%TY`.</sup>

Comment: Thank You, you save my day!